# How to replace fragments dynamically on ListView click?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

My application consists of a list view on the left hand side, that acts as a menu. By clicking on list items, I dynamically replace fragments. Currently, this works only particular.

Look at my callback method, that is responsible for replacements:

```
public void onNavigationDrawerFragmentItemSelected(int position) {

    switch(position) {
        case 0:
            if(!mTwoPanelsUsed) {
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, mListFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            } else {
                findViewById(R.id.container_2).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.container_1, mListFragment)
                        .replace(R.id.container_2, mDetailsFragment)
                        .addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            if(!mTwoPanelsUsed) {
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, mRecordFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            } else {
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container_1, mRecordFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                findViewById(R.id.container_2).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            if(!mTwoPanelsUsed) {
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, mSettingsFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            } else {
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container_1, mSettingsFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                findViewById(R.id.container_2).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            if(!mTwoPanelsUsed) {
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, mAboutFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            } else {
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container_1, mAboutFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                findViewById(R.id.container_2).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

Everything works fine, except case 0. This one works only the first time. After i changed to another fragment, the mListFragment for container_1 is not displayed. There is only a white field on the screen.

This is my layout xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    android:id="@+id/recording_view"
    tools:context=".RecordingListActivity">

    <!-- static drawer navigation -->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:name="com.iav.viraprecorder.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"/>

    <!-- dynamic content -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:id="@+id/container_1"></FrameLayout>

    <!-- dynamic content -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:id="@+id/container_2"></FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Can someone tell me, how to make the the mListFragment visible again?

Thanks!

EDIT 1:

Screenshot from start of the App:
[image: App Start]

Screenshot from going back to first menu item after visiting another:
[image]

EDIT 2:

Code of mListFragment alias RecordingListFragment:

```
package com.iav.viraprecorder;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.iav.viraprecorder.model.DummyData;

public class RecordingListFragment extends ListFragment {

    // log tag
    private static final String TAG = RecordingListFragment.class.getName();

    private RecordingListFragmentCallbacks mRecordingListFragmentCallbacks = sDummyRecordingListFragmentCallbacks;

    private ListView mListView;

    private RecordingListAdapter mAdapter;

    public RecordingListFragment() {
    }

    private static RecordingListFragmentCallbacks sDummyRecordingListFragmentCallbacks = new RecordingListFragmentCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onRecordingListFragmentItemSelected(String id) {
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        if (!(activity instanceof RecordingListFragmentCallbacks)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Activity must implement fragment's callbacks.");
        }

        mRecordingListFragmentCallbacks = (RecordingListFragmentCallbacks) activity;

    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        // Reset the active callbacks interface to the dummy implementation.
        mRecordingListFragmentCallbacks = sDummyRecordingListFragmentCallbacks;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recording_list, container, false);

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mListView = getListView();
        mAdapter = new RecordingListAdapter(getActivity(), DummyData.getRecordingList());

        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        mRecordingListFragmentCallbacks.onRecordingListFragmentItemSelected(
                DummyData.getRecordingList().get(position).getId());
    }

    public interface RecordingListFragmentCallbacks {
        public void onRecordingListFragmentItemSelected(String recordingId);
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you want navigation side drawer right??

Comment: I have got the navigation drawer on the left side as a menu. Right next to this, there is a list of "recordings" and next to this a details view for a selected recording (case 0). I want to restore the list of recordings, that is placed in container_1 (the middle).

Comment: If you put screenshot then it will be very useful to understand the problem

Comment: So I added some Screenshots!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this helps but i have a doubt that you would have overseen setting visibility for container1.

```
  case 0:
        if(!mTwoPanelsUsed) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, mListFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        } else {
            findViewById(R.id.container_2).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.container_1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container_1, mListFragment)
                    .replace(R.id.container_2, mDetailsFragment)
                    .addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }
        break;
```

if this doesn't work, please let me know.

Comment: what gets executed? The if loop or the else loop for case 0?

Comment: On tablets, the else part gets executed. Thats the point I am currently working on.

Comment: Take a look at the screenshots I have submitted.

Comment: can you post the code of the mListFragment?why haven't you replaced the container_1 with a new instance of mListFragment everytime first item is selected ?

Comment: have you tried to replace the container_1 with a new instance of RecordingListFragment everytime first item is selected ?

Comment: Yes this works, but I think this is no good solution, because then the fragment existis multiple times, or?